# Tools to create a Spam Checker Service in Java or Python

Tags: spam-prevention

Let's say I want to create a reusable REST web service that allows checking whether a piece of text/ blog comment is spam, once for all. (sick of adding this feature in every web app I work on)

Which tools, libraries, frameworks, that would nicely integrate to either Java or Python, would you recommend to accomplish this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Did you look at [RECAPTCHA](http://recaptcha.net/)? Do you want to build something from scratch? or can you use an exisiting tool like this one?

Another one that comes to my mind is [UCLASSIFY](http://www.uclassify.com/), it is a free web service where you can easily create your own text classifiers.

Comment: Ideally, I would like to avoid captchas as I juste hate them.

My goal is to reuse whatever libraries (reverend, orange, spambayes, whatever, pyzor, ..) or higher level tools that could allow me to build a simple webservice that I can query from my apps, to know whether some piece of text is spam or ham